# R dataframe with special cumsum

Tags: r, cumulative-sum, cumsum

I have a dateframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(grp = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)), t = c(1:5, 1:5), value = c(-1, 5, 9, -15, 6, 5, 1, 7, -11, 9))

# Limits for desired cumulative sum (CumSum)

maxCumSum <- 8

minCumSum <- 0
```

What I would like to calculate is a cumulative sum of value by group (grp) within the values of maxCumSum and minCumSum. The respective table dt2 should look something like this:

```
grp     t       value   CumSum
a       1       -1      0
a       2       5       5
a       3       9       8
a       4       -15     0
a       5       6       6
b       1       5       5
b       2       1       6
b       3       7       8
b       4       -11     0
b       5       9       8
```

Think of CumSum as a water storage with has a certain maximum capacity and the level of which cannot sink below zero.

The normal cumsum does obviously not do the trick since there are no limitations to maximum or minimum. Has anyone a suggestion how to achieve this? In the real dataframe there are of course more than 2 groups and far more than 5 times.

Many thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer but then deleted it because I realise I am not sure about the requirements here. Is the reason it goes from 8 to 0 when value is -15 in group A because you have subtracted 15, or do you always want it to go back down to 0 once the maximum is reached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is create a function which calculate the cumsum until it reach the max value and start again at the min value like this:

```r
df <- data.frame(grp = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)), t = c(1:5, 1:5), value = c(-1, 5, 9, -15, 6, 5, 1, 7, -11, 9))
library(dplyr)

maxCumSum <- 8
minCumSum <- 0
f <- function(x, y) max(min(x + y, maxCumSum), minCumSum)
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  mutate(CumSum = Reduce(f, value, 0, accumulate = TRUE)[-1])
#> # A tibble: 10 × 4
#> # Groups:   grp [2]
#>    grp       t value CumSum
#>    <chr> <int> <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1 a         1    -1      0
#>  2 a         2     5      5
#>  3 a         3     9      8
#>  4 a         4   -15      0
#>  5 a         5     6      6
#>  6 b         1     5      5
#>  7 b         2     1      6
#>  8 b         3     7      8
#>  9 b         4   -11      0
#> 10 b         5     9      8
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>